# Can't push to own repository: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, github

I've looked around Stackoverflow, but I haven't found a solution to my issue.

I've just created a new repository and ran the following commands:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:me/my-app.git
git push -u origin master
```

And it errors out,

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What could be going wrong? I've never had this issue before.

Comment: If you type ‘git remote -v’ what is the result you get?

Comment: The repo that I added by running `git remote add origin git@github.com:me/my-app.git`

Comment: Have you tried to type URL in https format?

Comment: Do you have SSH keys on your machine? Is the public key associated with your GitHub account or repository deploy keys? If yes, try to debug authentication issues with `ssh -v git@github.com`